# Ohm's law deviation

Tags: condensed-matter, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

In terms of superconductivities and diodes (I do not know anything else except these), Ohm's law deviate from a linear relation. I search many titles or tags for this but I did not understand properly how it becomes. I wonder somethings related with this.

- What is the basic of this deviation?
- How it is deviate?
- Why there is linear relation for metal conductors, if is it true?

Comment: Many physics things are linear under certain approximations and limits. Some things aren't. Explaining why semiconductors may (or may not) obey Ohm's "Law" takes a good intro to semiconductor physics. Note that capacitors and inductors don't obey Ohm's law either, and they aren't even weird materials.

Answer (score 2):

Ohm's law is a misnomer. It is not actually a true law, in the sense of Coulomb's of Ampère's; rather it is a 'rule of thumb' that applies pretty well in most circumstances. You will certainly not get a nobel price for finding an exception! A more general form of Ohm's law is 
$$\mathbf{J} = \sigma \mathbf{E},$$where $\mathbf{J}$ is the current density, $\sigma$ the conductivity and $\mathbf{E}$ the electric field.
Now in this form, you can easily find a classical derivation, due to Drude, (which is totally inaccurate but does make some good qualitative predictions

Answer (score -1):

Ohms law states that the voltage and current will maintain a linear relationship under the pretenses that the material is kept at the same physical condition. This often falters at higher voltages/current because of the material increases in temperature resulting in micro changes to the way electrons move.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which focuses on the reason why ohm's law isn't universally linear. You only mention that it _is_, without any detailed justification. Can you elaborate on the last phrase (" micro changes to the way electrons move")?