# Does V=IR define resistance for any conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electrical-resistance

Just wanted to confirm if the statement is always true or not

Comment: relevant post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247555/ohms-law-deviation

Comment: @IamAStudent hi, i checked the post you've linked but my question does not involve ohms law (v=ir =/= ohms law)

Comment: my apologies. What is the equation $V=IR$ called?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to somewhat contradict the other answers. They are right in saying that $V=IR$ is only true for certain materials where $R$ is constant.

However, your wording is about asking if "this defines resistance", so you would then want to have the equation
$$R=\frac VI$$

and in this case you can say this "always holds" if this is what you define resistance to be. Then you can have materials where the ratio between the applied voltage and resulting current is not constant, but you can still apply your definition of resistance by calculating $V/I$ and seeing that it does not remain constant.$^*$

It is for this reason that the undergraduate lab director at my university says that $R=V/I$ should be the *definition* of resistance, and that actually Ohm's law is given by $\mathbf J=\sigma\mathbf E$ for a *constant* $\sigma$ which then leads to $V=IR$ for a *constant* $R$.

---

$^*$ For example for a diode that only allows current flow in one direction, yet exhibits ohmic behavior when current flows in the other direction, you would say that $R=\infty$ (poor math talk) when $V<0$ (trying to push current in the wrong direction) and $R=V/I$ when $V>0$ (trying to push current the right way).

Comment: I agree. For a diode in the forward direction, there is also the differential resistance, which is about $r \approx 25/I \ \Omega$ where the current is in mA. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387030/differential-resistance-vs-r-fracui

Comment: With this definition $ P=VI = I^2R$ still holds so I agree.

Comment: +1 for "poor math talk" ... and for a good answer.

Comment: I am not sure it is always possible to define R as V/I. Take the example of a non-homogeneous doped semiconductor and consider the generalized Ohm's law $\vec J = -\sigma \nabla V - \sigma S \nabla T$. There will be (in addition to the Seebeck effect), a non-homogeneous Thomson heating across the resistor, as well as (possibly) a Peltier effect at the ends of the material. I think this can lead to two different values for R, if R is defined as V/I, according to the direction of the current. Am I missing something?

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson Do you mean to say we can't use the definition if there is time dependence for a constant $V$?

Comment: No, I am talking about a steady-state, but I do not ignore thermoelectric effects, that's the only difference. I use a non-homogeneous semiconductor to ensure there will be a non homogeneous heating across the (resistive) material, regardless of whether the Seebeck coefficient depends on temperature. Since the resistance is usually temperature dependent, there will be a different resistance measured (as V/I) if the current is reversed.

Comment: I should have written "Since the resistivity is usually temperature dependent..." in my last sentence.

Comment: By the way, this also holds for a homogeneous metal such as nickel or platinum (if not all metals). While the Joule heat doesn't change with current reversal, the Thomson heat does. Since the resistivity is temperature dependent, when the current is passed in a direction, a part of the sample is cooled, while the other part is heated up (let's say the temperature of the ends of the sample are kept at a fixed temperature, it may not even need to be the same). In that case the voltage measured depends on the direction of the current. The temperature distribution is not symmetric with respect to

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson Ok? So then what's wrong with having a piecewise resistance if we are talking about steady state? If you look at my footnote a give a (much simpler) example of resistance for when the potential has different polarity.

Comment: I agree, it is exactly similar, for most (or all) metals, semiconductors, etc. The resistance depends on the current direction, so R is never uniquely defined. You're right that it's fine and there's no problem. It just looked like R=V/I yield a single well defined value while it isn't the case.

Comment: Does your answer mean that the resistivity depends on the current? Because the resistance is equal to the integral of the resistivity with respect to the spatial dimensions of the sample. It does seem a bit strange to me.

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson No. I am saying this would be more of an operational definition. Where you apply a voltage, measure the current that results, and this ratio would be the resistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90746/discussion-between-thermomagnetic-condensed-boson-and-aaron-stevens).

Comment: Thank you! I wish they've phrased the question as "does R=V/I define the resistance for any conductor" so that students like me wouldn't fall into the bait of nonohmic resistors

Answer (score 0):

This equation is obeyed by the ohmic devices. There are objects (diodes,LED) which doesn't follow Ohm's law ($V=IR$). Such devices are called Non Ohmic devices. Eventhough they don't follow Ohms law they do have effective resistance, not defined as $V=IR$. The difference between Ohmic and non Ohmic devices are shown in the link. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236990/what-is-the-difference-between-ohmic-and-non-ohmic-devices

Answer (score 0):

The equation/formula $V=IR$ is named the ohm's law. The law was named after the German physicist Georg Ohm, who, in a treatise published in 1827. Any conductor that has current passing through has some degree of resistance, and as long as you can quantify how much resistance, you can apply ohm's law.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of a linear (ideal) approximation,  V=IR is the standard rule and applies not only to electrical circuits but also to mechanisms and hydraulic systems.

As such, it is the default model for what are called *ohmic* systems- where effort losses are linearly proportional to flow variables.

Answer (score 0):

This law is also not true for when you're dealing with EMI. Potential difference will be zero across a circuit yet a current will flow. 
Rather use current density = conductivity * Electric field. (This is the original ohm's law from which V= IR is derived . Just substitute J = i/A and E = V/l , you'll see)

Comment: What is / are EMI? And isn't simply R=0 in this case?

Comment: EMI - Electromagnetic Induction ; R = resistivity*(length/area). Putting resistivity = 1/conductivity in the above formula, you'll derive Ohm's law.